# WP remove dots in the end of post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP theme  with dynamically loaded posts and 3 dots in the end of the each blog post. I need to remove these 3 dots.

I tried:

1. In `index.php`:

   1.1 Manually commented dots in template. This removed dots only for first 10 posts and in another 90 post dots reamained.

   1.2 I tried to use `.slice(0, -3)` to cut off the dots. It didn't work for me. It worked for 10 post without `(window).scroll`, but when I added it it didn't work at all.

   ```
     jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
       jQuery('.hideifneed').each(function(){
           var text = jQuery(this).text();
           var removeDots = text.slice(0, -3)
           console.log(removeDots);
       });

   });
   ```
2. Input pieces of code in the end of `functions.php`. None of the code below helped me.

I tried this(2.1):

```
 function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
       return '';
    }
    add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

And this(2.2):

```
function change_excerpt( $more ) {
        if(post_type_exists('services')){
           return '';
        }
     return '...';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'change_excerpt');
```

And this (2.3): `<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo $excerpt;?>`

And this (2.4):

```
function custom_excerpt() {
 $text=preg_replace( "/\\[&hellip;\\]/",'place here whatever you want to replace',get_the_excerpt());
echo '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
}
```

And this (2.5): `<?php remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop'); ?>`
And I also tried to rewrite the `excerpt` function (2.6):

```
function wp_new_excerpt($text)
{
    if ($text == '')
    {
        $allowed_ends = array('.', '!', '?');
        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace('...', ']]>', $text);
        $text = strip_tags($text);
        $text = nl2br($text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 10000);
        $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
        if (count($words) > $excerpt_length) {
            array_pop($words);
            array_push($words, '[]');
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_new_excerpt');
```

What else can I try? Do you have any ideas?

**Edited:**
The only thing that works in my case - in admin panel > post > post settings > Excerpt Off. This removes dots only for one post, so it is not really an option

Comment: did you try using the same code as you did on single.php. Note: Single.php is located under your current theme folder which would be: site.tld/wp-content/themes/your-theme/single.php

Comment: @Yasir, thanks for the hint, I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try to locate these 3 dots under your theme files.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works this:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```